# Is a manifold orientable if it has an atlas which has negative determinants for all of its transition maps?

Tags: differential-geometry

I've tried to construct a non-vanishing n-form on a manifold given this condition, like one for an orientable Riemannian manifold. However, the partition of unity won't work; there's a change of sign in the intersection of two coordinate neighborhoods. What else can I do to prove or disprove this assertion?

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider a Möbius band built out of three squares.

Comment: Thanks!With your hint I constructed an atlas for Möbius band by modify the one for RP^2,with all determinants negative!